# ASP.NET/Vb.net: How to create a frame after an image is uploaded?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, graphics

i would like to create a fixed size frame for user photos uploaded.
I've tought: i, can create a fixed sized image (200 width x 600 height for example), with my personal frame (top, left, bottom, right element graphics) , and in the center a transparency.

Ok, but i don't know how to merge the photo into the frame and save the new photo format.
Does anybody have some piece of code to help me ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use System.Drawing.Imaging and then put the image inside;
Read about it:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/aspnet_web_graphics.aspx